# Plot formula in matlab so that it looks like a handwritten formula

Tags: matlab, formula

Matlab calculates an integral for me. I do get a good result and can work with it. However, I would like to 'plot' the function in a nice way. As it is, I get the result as a textformula, which looks like :(ni^2*(exp((e*V)/(k*T))-1))/((2*ni*...

But I would like to see the formula as you would write it when you write formula with your hands. I hope it is clear what I mean by that. Is there a way I can do that?

Kind regards

Comment: If I understand correctly then I don't think matlab would help you. You could try latex [link] (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) . That's supposing you need this to get the formula printed or published or something. If it's just to see it for yourself it wouldn't be worth it.